# widget is not coming in the home screen

Tags: xml, android-widget, android-manifest

here is my manifest file can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? the error message is "could not load the widget". I googled the error and people suggested to check the layout classes and widget classes. I have used a button but still the error is coming. Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bmsce.appointext"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_appointext"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<!-- widget starts here -->        

        <activity 
            android:name="com.appointext.widget.Widget"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> -->
                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.appointext.widget.Widget" 
            android:label="Appointext widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                android:resource="@xml/widget1_info" />
        </receiver>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest shows your are setting the same class name for activity and widget. Make sure your widget class extends AppWidgetProvider.

```
   android:name="com.appointext.widget.Widget"
```